# Project Server 2013 Site not available

Tags: 2013, project-server, windows-server-2012-r2

My project server 2013 website is throwing following error.

[image]

**Following is my error log**

[image]

How would I fix it?

**Update**

When I check my ProjectWebAppPool in IIS [image]it is stopped but when I try to start it and enter the url of ProjectServer site then again it gets stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"http Error 503 the Service is Unavailable" error means the App Pool of the the Project Web Application is down.

Go to the IIS and Check the App Pool of Project Web Application and Start it.

Comment: Please see my update in the question.

Comment: Now you should the check the event log why it is stopping, may be account having the issue(under which app Pool is running).

Comment: Application pool ProjectWebAppPool has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it started a worker process to serve the application pool

Comment: is it giving to you any reasons? login failure or dont have batch rights etc?

Comment: Done waqas bhai..........that was account expiry issue...........thanx

Comment: great, glad i help you out

Comment: Waqas bhai I am trying to create a Dashboard for my Project Server 2013 since one month but to no avail trying different things like datazen,powerpivot,performance point services,securepoint services so on.Can you guide me some steps or reference so that I could create a dashboard from scratch?

Comment: i am sorry, i am not the powe ruser...You can open a new question and people with related skills will guide you...Inshallah